# verifying sender email requires user to log in to sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here but it doesn't seem to make any sense to me that when I try to use the SendGrid API V3 to verify a sender email it asks the user to log in to sendgrid. In this case it was an email of a customer of ours who obviously is not expected to have a sendgrid account. I just want him to be able to send email from my product. So when I try to verify an email, the email goes to the customer but then it asks to log in to sendgrid?

This workflow doesn't make any sense. Why would they need to have Sendgrid? They're using my software to be able to send email. I just need them to verify that they own the email address. That's all. I would have assumed that Sendgrid would just send one email to them to verify that they own the address and then upon clicking it would simply just verify. In this case, it's asking them to log into Sendgrid.

Cany anyone shed any light on this? What am I missing here?

Here's the API call I'm making

https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/verified_senders

with this JSON data

```
{
  "nickname": "Sam",
  "from_email": "sam@sam.com",
  "from_name": "ABC",
  "reply_to": "sam@sam.com",
  "reply_to_name": "Sam",
  "address": "1234 Fake St",
  "city": "Fakeplace",
  "country": "USA"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Here's the link to the documentation which tells me that it should be as easy as them clicking on a link to verify the email.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification

Then I'm not sure why when clicking on a link, it actually asks them to login to Sendgrid.

Answer (score 1):

You are using old sendgrid sender identity API.

Pass the JSON payload like this.

```
{
"nickname": "jhon Doe",
"from" : {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "name": "Jhon Doe"
   },
"reply_to": {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "name": "jhon Doe"
   },
"address": "1234 Fake St.",
"city": "San Francisco",
"country": "United States",
"state": "CA",
"zip": "94105",
}
```

For more detail follow this following link.

https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/senders/create-a-sender-identity-1

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for this. I'll try this out. Cheers!

Comment: I had the same issue and I can confirm this works. Very strange though, the API docs have several issues and are misleading.